# Ошибка с базой данных в Flask (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, flask, sqlalchemy

Я не понимаю в чем ошибка, вот код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgresql:123@localhost/base'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, text, tags):
        self.text = text.strip()
        self.tags = [
            Tag(text=tag.strip()) for tag in tags.split(',')
        ]


class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)

    message_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('message.id'), nullable=False)
    message = db.relationship('Message', backref=db.backref('tags', lazy=True))


db.create_all()


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/main', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    return render_template('main.html', messages=Message.query.all())


@app.route('/add_message', methods=['POST'])
def add_message():
    text = request.form['text']
    tag = request.form['tag']

    db.session.add(Message(text, tag))
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('main'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Помогите пж, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего PostgreSQL не запущен.

Comment: А как его запустить?

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/12/index

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте настройки Postgres, файл /etc/postgresql/xx/main/**pg_hba.conf** должен содержать:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Необходимо, чтобы было **trust**